# Assigning upper case variables to commands

Tags: ksh, variable-substitution

While trying to decipher some scripts written by former employees of my current company, in many of the scripts, I came across the following statements which assign variables to some commands as shown below:

```
CAT=cat
GREP=grep
SED=sed
```

Later in the script, I see that they have used these variables instead of the regular commands:

```
$GREP -v "^#" `dirname $0`/abcdfilename | while read line
do
<some loop operations>
done
```

I don't see the point in using this variable instead of using `grep` directly. My questions are:

- Is there a point in doing the grep or sed (in our case) this way?
- Is this the result of someone trying to write a script with the intention of making it harder for another person to understand?
- Or is this simply an example of bad scripting?

Comment: Does your company have a coding convention? I have seen this sort of stuff here before: the reason is usually that the commands are *usually* found in `PATH` and named as expected, but the script may have to be run in an environment where they might not be in `PATH` or named as expected. (That would be very unusual for `grep`, `cat`, etc., - the times I have seen them are for programs that you typically have to install separately.)

Comment: No coding conventions used that I am aware of now. Yep, the use of common commands like `grep`, `cat` etc here are strange.

Comment: It might be that the author found it useful to easily change commands from `grep` to `egrep` or `awk` to `gawk`, or a custom build in another location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an argument for making nearly anything that you use repeatedly throughout a script into a varuable, because then you can re-define it once and have it ripple through the rest of the script.

You might argue that basically the same thing could be done with a simple sed search/replace but many users are wary of search/replace, since it's not that hard to accidentally replace something you did not intend to replace.

In fact, I'd suggest this improvement over their existing version:

```
GREP=${GREP:-/bin/grep}
```

meaning that GREP will be set to whatever the user sets it to in the shell, or if NOT set, then to /bin/grep

This way a user can override 'grep' on the fly.

```
$ export GREP=/bin/fgrep
$ ./path/to/script.sh
```

Answer (score 6):

There are different implementations for a standard command, on a system. Like in Solaris 10 and earlier, you have `/bin/sh` is the old Bourne shell and `/usr/xpg4/bin/sh` Is POSIX compliant shell. Or on OSX, you have BSD sed when calling `sed` and GNU sed when calling `gsed`. You can chose what implementation you want to use in your script.

So it's easier to change what implementation in your script when you used variable. When you want GNU sed:

```
SED=gsed
```

If you don't use variable, then you must replace all occurrences of `sed` in your script. Although you can do it easily, it's considered bad programming practice.

Comment: Agreed.  I seem to see this more often in older scripts.  

I don't think it's just about locations of the executables, either.  I always had the idea that it was related to a period of time when common utilities would be rewritten or expanded, and released under a different name.  An example is all the different kinds of $AWK there still are. (mawk, gawk, nawk, pgawk.. the man page lists a bunch.)

Answer (score 1):

It's probably an example of premature optimization.

How many alternatives does that machine, or *any* machine have for **sed**, **grep**, and **awk**?  I'd wager the universal average is close to 1.0.  Given two choices on a particular machine, what are the odds that the implementations differ such that the script fails with the version found on the PATH and works with the other?  If that does happen, is the solution more likely to be changing the script, or the PATH?  If changing the script proves to be the answer, what are the odds of finding at least one invocation of **grep** instead of **$GREP**?  The deck is stacked against the need for any indirection, and against it working as intended if ever it's needed.

I wouldn't fight the culture.  If there's some preference in your shop for **$GREP** or **/usr/bin/grep** or just **grep**, I'd probably go along to get along.  Otherwise, KISS: avoid indirection until the need for it arises.